# Django-cms can't display menu correctly

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I create some pages, but my menu can't display correctly.

[image: My main page]

I don't know the problem is in the css or in the module importing error.

As the django-cms tutorial descript, the correct page is as follows:

[image: correct page]

Do I descript my question clearly? Thanks all visit this problem.

Comment: Have you used a template for your navigation? Look a bit like the styles are missing - either you are using the wrong template or your statics aren't loaded correctly.

Comment: My statics folder is empty. But I built my project according to the step in the official website. I imported the "menu" module in the "INSTALLED_APPS". But still can't work.

Comment: The menu app just provides an app to generate the menu. You'll still need to provide styles & markup in order to display your menu as you want.

Comment: Could you please provide me some turorials about how to supply css of menu app in django project?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this;

http://www.cssportal.com/css3-menu-generator/

It provides plenty of customisation to help you with the styling & then shows the markup so you should also be able to make your menu template match the markup required.